# Updating External Variable Inside JavaScript Closure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I'm currently working on a project involving JavaScript closures, and I've encountered a situation where an external variable doesn't seem to update as expected within the closure. Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<null | HTMLElement>(null)
  const [menuStates, setMenuStates] = useState<{ [key: number]: boolean }>({})
  const openMore = Boolean(anchorEl)
  const handleClick = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>,
    index: number,
  ): void => {

    setMenuStates((prevMenuStates) => ({
      ...prevMenuStates,
      [index]: true,
    }))
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)

  }
return(
///
<Stepper activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical">
{Steps.map((step, index) => (
  <React.Fragment key={index}>
    <IconButton
      aria-label="more"
      id={`basic-button-${index}`}
      aria-controls={openMore ? `basic-menu-${index}` : undefined}
      aria-expanded={openMore ? 'true' : undefined}
      aria-haspopup="true"
      onClick={(event): void => handleClick(event, index)}
    >
      <MoreVertIcon />
    </IconButton>
     <Menu
      id={`basic-menu-${index}`}
      MenuListProps={{
        'aria-labelledby': `basic-button-${index}`,
      }}
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      open={openMore}
      onClose={handleClose}
    >

      <MenuList>
        <MenuItem>
          <ListItemText>Edit{String(index)}</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>
          <ListItemText>Remove{String(index)}</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>
        <Divider />
        <MenuItem
          disabled={steps[index]}
          onClick={(): void => handleComplete(index)}
        >
          <ListItemText>Complete{String(index)}</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>
      </MenuList>
    </Menu>
  </React.Fragment>
))}
</Stepper>
```

In this setup, I'm using the Steps array to create dynamic elements. However, when the handleClick function is triggered by clicking the IconButton, it seems the index value passed to StepperMenu doesn't update as expected. I suspect this might be related to JavaScript closures.
eg. after become index2 for every menu.

If anyone has insights into why this behavior might be occurring or suggestions on how to handle it, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Please feel free to share any thoughts or advice on how I can better manage the closure and ensure the index reflects the correct value.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I tried to separate into  and  but it didn't work.

Comment: Post handleClick too

Comment: "*the index value passed to StepperMenu doesn't update as expected*" - which `StepperMenu`? Which `index`, the `map` callback parameter? How and why did you expect it to "update"? What did you experience instead?

Comment: sorry, I just update the codes. there is array = [ false, true, true] to disable/ enable the button. the result is three MoreVertIcon show up to the screen but if I open it, every three menu shows array's index 2 result.